# How do I delete a group in RCloud Notebook Permission/Group Management?

Tags: rcloud

How do I delete a group in RCloud Notebook Permission/Group Management (Found in Advanced -> Manage Groups)?
There doesn't seem to be a way to delete the group after it was created.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking (again!) Pasting the same comment for the benefit of the internets. Currently you can't do that. IIRC the reasoning was that we don't know what notebooks are encrypted with the group key, so it would be dangerous to delete the group because it could make notebooks inaccessible by anyone.